# Displaying Y Cb and Cr components in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a RGB image of dimensions 640*480. I have converted it to Y Cb Cr image by using the Matlab command Rgbtoycbcr but i want to display the Y Cb Cr components separately as Figures. How do i do it?

Comment: so does any answer provided below helped you? If so please accept either of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is an extension of Benoit_11's code. Instead of displaying the values of each channel as a greyscale image, this code fills the other channels with a constant value of 50%. This way the influence of each channel to the final picture is easier to observe. Especially the importance of the Y channel is obvious.

```
RGB = imread('board.tif');
YCBCR = rgb2ycbcr(RGB);

figure;

lb={'Y','Cb','Cr'};

for channel=1:3
subplot(1,3,channel)
YCBCR_C=YCBCR;
YCBCR_C(:,:,setdiff(1:3,channel))=intmax(class(YCBCR_C))/2;
imshow(ycbcr2rgb(YCBCR_C))
title([lb{channel} ' component'],'FontSize',18);
end
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 3):

You can display each component as you would do for the red, green or blue channels of a RGB image indexing the 3rd dimension of your image.

Simple example:

```
RGB = imread('board.tif');
YCBCR = rgb2ycbcr(RGB);

figure;

subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(YCBCR(:,:,1))
title('Y component','FontSize',18);

subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(YCBCR(:,:,2))
title('Cb component','FontSize',18);

subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(YCBCR(:,:,3))
title('Cr component','FontSize',18);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
rgbImage = imread('C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg'); %# A sample RGB image
A = [65.481 -37.797 112; ...       %# A 3-by-3 matrix of scale factors
 128.553 -74.203 -93.786; ...
 24.966 112 -18.214];
%# First convert the RGB image to double precision, scale its values to the
%#   range 0 to 1, reshape it to an N-by-3 matrix, and multiply by A:
ycbcrImage = reshape(double(rgbImage)./255,[],3)*A;

%# Shift each color plane (stored in each column of the N-by-3 matrix):
ycbcrImage(:,1) = ycbcrImage(:,1)+16;
ycbcrImage(:,2) = ycbcrImage(:,2)+128;
ycbcrImage(:,3) = ycbcrImage(:,3)+128;

%# Convert back to type uint8 and reshape to its original size:
ycbcrImage = reshape(uint8(ycbcrImage),size(rgbImage));
imshow(ycbcrImage);
ycbcry = ycbcrImage;
ycbcry(:,:,2) = 2;
ycbcry(:,:,3) = 2;
rgb1 = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcry);
figure, imshow(rgb1);
% display the cb component as a color image
ycbcru = ycbcrImage;
ycbcru(:,:,1) = 4;
ycbcru(:,:,3) = 4;
rgb2 = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcru);
figure, imshow(rgb2);
% display the cr component as a color image
ycbcrv = ycbcrImage;
ycbcrv(:,:,1) = 8;
ycbcrv(:,:,2) = 8;
rgb3 = ycbcr2rgb(ycbcrv);
figure, imshow(rgb3);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the formatting of your code.

Comment: could you explain little bit why you did so long?